# What is matrix inequality such as $A>0$ or $A\succ 0$?

Tags: matrices, soft-question, optimization, terminology

*I am trying to gather here different meanings of the same symbol, inequality symbol or the succ symbol. I find many other use them so many different ways.*

Sometimes, $A>0$ means $\bar x^T A \bar x >0$. Sometimes, $A>0$ means element-wise i.e. $a_{i,j}>0$ for all $i,j$.

> How do I know which definition of inequality people are meaning?

**Examples**

> 1. **[Solved]** Meaning of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6hOW.png)? Why is it $A\succ 0$?  [LMI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk8m4.png) and [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4InWF.png) from Boyd's book. $\succ$ means positive-definiteness: check PD with Cholenksy decomposition, positive eigen-value check or Sylvester criteria. [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12700861#12700861).
> 2. Strict matrix inequality defined [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVKHf.png) requiring symmetric matrices.

Comment: "How do I know which definition of inequality people are meaning?" You can't from the tiny snippets you are posting. Usually they will have defined what they mean earlier in the text.

Answer (score 3):

The curved symbol (in my experience) means that the difference is positive definite (so, with zero it means that the matrix is positive definite). The $>$ depends on the context.

Comment: +1 Sure, you can check the PD with Sylvester criterion, positive eigen values check or Cholensky decomposition. Sylvester in the example easiest.

Answer (score -3):

For squared matrix $A$, $A>0$ means that $A$ is positive definite. Also, the real parts of all of $A$s eigenvalues are positive.